# PHP Http Referer redirects me even if am visiting from Referer

Tags: php, api, http, redirect, referer

```
<?php
ob_start();

require_once '../autoit/includes/db.php';
include 'ss_setting.php'; 

if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    // redirect them to your desired location
    header('location:../autoit/index.php');

}
?>
```

this code only works when I add this 
`<a href="http://127.0.0.1/autoit/gencode.php?action=create">Visit code</a>` to another php address.

I want to add shorten link like ouo.io or adfly to only get access my
link it always redirect me to index.php even if am i visiting from
another site

Comment: You want to just users who refered from adfly can access to your site? am i correct?

Comment: @ttrasn yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

If adfly domain is `adf.ly` we can use [`parseurl()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to check exact domain.

```
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$refData = parse_url($ref);

if($refData['host'] !== 'adf.ly') {
    header('location:../autoit/index.php');
    //or what you want
}
```

Comment: he still redirect me to location:../autoit/index.php even if i came from adfly or ouo

Comment: @MohamedAbdelFattah maybe adfly referrer domain is not `adf.ly`.

Comment: also add this in another php  `<form action="http://127.0.0.1/autoit/gencode.php?action=create" method="get" name="redirect"></form>
<script> document.forms['redirect'].submit() </script>`  and its also redirect me to index